# How to Know Available Data from my website for my Google Custom Search

Tags: google-custom-search

I'm trying to implement a Google Custom Search Engine into my website. So far, I've been able of changing my snippets layout, and show the variables Google shows in its examples:

http://googleajaxsearchapi.blogspot.com.es/2010/04/rendering-custom-data-in-custom-search.html

Well, in the examples, everything looks great, BECAUSE THEY KNOW THE VALUES THEY MAY PRINT. I mean, if you see this snippet:

```
<div id="mysite_thumbnail">
  <div data-if="Vars.thumbnail" class="gs-image-box gs-web-image-box">
    <a class="gs-image" data-attr="{href:url, target:target}">
      <img class="gs-image" data-attr="{src:thumbnail.src, width:48, height: 48}"/>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

it's pretty clear that "Vars" is holding some data GSE is printing. My problem is that I don't know what "Vars" holds, and when developing my view I can't know if the value is there, and what is its name.

So, the question is: How can I print "Vars"? I suppose is a js variable you may obtain from the jsapi, but juss guessing, console.log() was not working for me, :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally found out how to post the data:

From Google Search Engine Api documentation:

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/js/rendering?hl=es&csw=1#richsnip

You only have to add the following code in your snippet:

```
<span data-body="JSON.stringify(Vars)"></span>
```

So, you'll have something like:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      // Load the Search API
      google.load('search', '1');

      // Set a callback to load the Custom Search Control when you page loads
      google.setOnLoadCallback(
      function(){
         new google.search.CustomSearchControl('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX').draw('cse');
         google.search.Csedr.addOverride("mysite_");
      },
      true);

      console.log(google);
</script>

   <div style="display:none">
      <div id="mysite_thumbnail">

         //This will show all Vars content
         <span data-body="JSON.stringify(Vars)"></span>

         <div data-if="Vars.thumbnail" class="gs-image-box gs-web-image-box">
            <a class="gs-image" data-attr="{href:url, target:target}">
               <img class="gs-image" data-attr="{src:thumbnail.src, width:48, height: 48}"/>
            </a>
         </div>
         <div data-ifel="Vars.thumbnail == 0" class="gs-image-box gs-web-image-box">
            <a class="gs-image" data-attr="{href:url, target:target}">
               <img class="gs-image" data-attr="{src:'XXXXX.png', width:115, height: 90}"/>
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div id="mysite_webResult">
         <div class="gs-webResult gs-result"
            data-vars="{longUrl:function() {
            var i = unescapedUrl.indexOf(visibleUrl);
            return i < 1 ? visibleUrl : unescapedUrl.substring(i);}}">
            <table>
               <tr>
                  <td valign="top">
                     <div data-if="Vars.richSnippet" data-attr="0"
                        data-body="render('thumbnail',richSnippet,{url:unescapedUrl,target:target})"></div>
                  </td>

                  <td valign="top">
                     <div class="gs-title">
                        <a class="gs-title" data-attr="{href:unescapedUrl,target:target}"
                           data-body="html(title)"></a>
                     </div>
                     <div class="gs-snippet" data-body="html(content)"></div>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: It's a good question and IMO the documentation is **a total mess**! Sorry I just flagged your answer as *not an answer* because I didn't see the information. You should make it clear in your answer that the important part is that you can just print the content of `Vars` using `<span data-body="JSON.stringify(Vars)"></span>`.

Comment: Hi @MrUpsidown, in fact, that was there hidden. I didn't indent the html, so it was automatically hidden by SO. I added the spaces, so now it´s clear, XD. Thanks to point it out!